# Limit Wagtail Custom Site Settings to Group or Site

Tags: django, wagtail

I am trying to create custom settings on a site by site basis for head/footer information. I have registered the settings and I'm able to edit the settings for each site, but other sites can see/edit these settings:

[image]

The code I have is:

```
@register_setting
class SiteSettings(BaseSetting, ClusterableModel):
    site_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    site_logo = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtailimages.Image',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name='+',
    )
    banner_color = models.CharField(
        max_length=6,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        help_text="Fill in a hex colour value"
    )
    include_footer = models.BooleanField(null=True)

    panels = [
        FieldPanel('site_name'),
        ImageChooserPanel('site_logo'),
        FieldPanel('banner_color'),
        FieldPanel('include_footer'),
        InlinePanel('footer', label="Footer",
                help_text='Select your contact/social media type and enter the phone number, email, or URL')
    ]
```

I tried overriding SiteSwitchForm, but it doesn't seem to get called.

```
# Override SiteSwitchForm

class SiteSwitchForm(SingleSiteSwitchForm):
    site = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[])

    class Media:
        js = [
            'wagtailmenus/js/site-switcher.js',
        ]

    def __init__(self, current_site, url_helper, **kwargs):
        initial = {'site': url_helper.get_action_url('edit', current_site.pk)}
        super().__init__(initial=initial, **kwargs)
        sites = []
        for site in Site.objects.filter(site_name__exact=self.site_name):
            sites.append((url_helper.get_action_url('edit', site.pk), site))
        self.fields['site'].choices = sites
```

I also tried:

```
def get_queryset(self, request):
    qs = super().get_queryset(request)
    return qs.filter(managed_by=request.user)
```

But that doesn't apply to BaseSettings.

Is there a way to make custom settings only visible to the group/site that owns the site?

Comment: Wagtail isn't as thoroughly multi-site-capable as I would like, but here's an article about multi-site Wagtail that might help you:  https://wagtail.io/blog/multi-site-wagtail/

Comment: I did follow that post, but the settings are editable by any user. I saw that the drop down is generated in the ```__init__``` method of SiteSwitchForm with ```for site in Site.objects.all()``` which is why I was hoping to just override that method and filter by Group (or just a singular site).

Answer (score 2):

Register the SiteSettings as ModelAdmin and override [ModelAdmin.get_queryset](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.0/reference/contrib/modeladmin/indexview.html#modeladmin-get-queryset) receives the request. So you can lookup the current site.

Now you only need a way to disable SiteSettings in settings menu.

Comment: I think I need to go this route. I tried it before, but I believe I got a 404 page and gave up too quickly.

Comment: It is obviously not the prettiest way but should work TM. For many listings there are wagtail hooks so you can customise the queryset. There isn't one for settings. Might be worth opening an issue with the feature request.